# Generating 80 random alphabet letters in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to generate 80 random letters of the English alphabet (capital letters) and display them in a row of 10 letters per row.
I have a similar code for bingo numbers but I'm not sure what to change to adapt it for the alphabet

```
bingo = 1 : 99; 
for i = 1 : 99
temp = bingo(i); 
swop = floor(rand * 99 + 1); 
bingo(i) = bingo(swop); 
bingo(swop) = temp;
end
for i = 1 : 10 : 81
disp(bingo(i : i + 9))
end
disp(bingo(91 : 99))
```

How do I adapt it for the alphabet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> letters = ‘A’:’Z’;
>> letters(randi(26, 8, 10))

ans =

  8×10 char array

    'VYKRHLSYXV'
    'XZXTBJTIYG'
    'DEUTCTHPOY'
    'XZYKVURFDJ'
    'QYRRSERTDF'
    'CMAEIMEGGG'
    'HUWSYLDNVQ'
    'ODYAAQMSGM'
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using 'for' function?